# No Linux driver for RT R8111G Ethernet chip found?

Tags: drivers, proprietary-drivers

For the hobby PC 'Atomic Pi', there's a problem with the Ethernet.
The original driver probably was for Windows, and the devices are sold with Linux; as their 16GB emmc drive is too small for Windows.
Linux doesn't seem to have any drivers for it.

The [Realtek website](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) lists a few Linux drivers for the r8111G,
the 8101, 8125, and 8168.
None of them work, card not even recognized, but the 8168 gets closest, in actually recognizing the ethernet card in Linux, and it comes by default with Ubuntu.
However, no data is ever sent or received through it, as it's some sort of generic driver that works for most of their ethernet cards, just not for the RTL8111G.

I was wondering if anyone could be of any help, in how to get the ethernet to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Realtek has hundreds of NICs with funky names - this NIC might very well be supported already. What's its PCI ID - find it with `lspci -nn` - it'll be in end of a string, e.g. [1002:731f]?

Comment: The result of lspci -nn is :
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)

Comment: Linux 5.7 definitely supports it, I've just checked the code. No idea how this particular kernel can be installed in your distro.